# XHTML Javascript code on one line

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, xhtml

In HTML5, I'm able to use special javascript characters on one line as follows:

```
<script> var x;If (x < 1){alert('</'+'script'+'>');} </script>
```

However, I'm trying to adapt my code to mobile devices, so I thought trying to abide to mobile profile 1.2 is good, however, I get all sorts of parsing errors with the above code such as:

```
character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
```

and

```
StartTag: invalid element name
```

and both errors highlight the "<" character.

One post here indicated I could use CDATA tags and somewhere else indicated that html comment tags may work, but the problem is both of those methods require javascript to be on its own line. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
var x;If (x < 1){alert('</'+'script'+'>');}    
// -->
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
var x;If (x < 1){alert('</'+'script'+'>');}    
// ]]>
</script>
```

Is there a way I can get this kind of javascript code all within one line and have it still execute properly without receiving parsing errors in the w3c validator?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a lower-case if, and you should also use escaped character codes:

```
var x;if (x < 1){alert('\x3C/script>');}
```

I don't think it's absolutely necessary, but you can also use an escaped character for the other end of the script tag as well:

```
var x;if (x < 1){alert('\x3C/script\x3E');}
```

Answer (score 0):

If should be lower case. if

```
var x;if (x < 1){alert('</'+'script'+'>');}
```

Comment: While this is absolutely true, I assume that it was just a typo on the OP's part when they typed up the example. I mean, it's not production code, that's for sure!

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions, depending on your situation.

1. If this is real XHTML, that is, served up with an XML file type (e.g. a document with a .xhtml extension), you won't need comments for the `<![CDATA[` delimiters at all. Oh, and you won't need to cut the `'</script>'` into pieces.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> <![CDATA[ var x;if (x < 1){alert('</script>');} ]]> </script>
   ```
2. (also with real XHTML), as an alternative you can simply replace each `<` with `&lt;` and each `&` with `&amp;` and then even the `<![CDATA[` is not necessary.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> var x;if (x &lt; 1){alert('&lt;/script>');} ]]> </script>
   ```
3. But if you're not sure if the result will be real XHTML or not, you will have to use comments for the `<![CDATA[` delimiters, yes. And the cut up `'</script>'`.
   However, you don't need `//` comments. `/*`..`*/` will do just fine!

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript"> /*<![CDATA[*/ var x;if (x < 1){alert('</'+'script'+'>');} /*]]>*/ </script>
   ```

By the way, I would cut between the `<` and the `/`, but that's just me.